# Mocking credit card transaction in java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, testing, mocking, payment

I'm currently working on a JAVA EE e-commerce application, and I'm wondering if it's possible to mock a credit card transaction on JAVA EE because I wanted to test the "payment part" of my application.

I hope that you have a solution to this particular issue.

For the record, I deploy my application on Glassfish, using a postgresql database.

Thank you

Comment: I believe payment gateway vendors provide developer access to use their gateway for testing. You need to check with them.